# How many even number greater than 300 can be formed from these numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Question is:

> If we have $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$. Find how many even number greater than
> $300$ can be formed from these digits, if the digits:
>
> (A) Can be repeated
> (B) Can not be repeated
>
> Answers given (A) $1530$, (B) $111$

My answer is like:

> (A) $(5^4 \times 2)+(5^3\times2)+(3\times5\times2)=1530$
>
> (B) $(1\times2\times3\times4\times2)+(2\times3\times4\times2)+\mathbf{(3\times3\times2)}= 114$

I believe the part in bold is where the problem is so I will explain how I went about it:

I have three slots _ _ _ the last must be $2$ or $4$ (even) so $2$ possible choices and the first can be $3, 4, 5$ so $3$ choices and the middle can be anything except the past $2$ choices so $5-2=3$ choices so $3\times3\times2$.

I answered the A part using slot method but whenever I try the B part I get $114$ as an answer.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure why the answer to part (A) is finite... surely with repeated digits you can build as large a number as you wish. Is there some additional constraint?

Comment: @Joffan this problem is from fundamental counting principle it would deviate from the lesson to add the idea of the infinite but I agree with you that the question needs to be more specific.

Comment: I just thought there might be a limit (unstated) on the number of digits in the numbers being formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For three digit numbers, when you have a 2 at the end, this works. When you have a 4 at the end, it does not. Instead of $3\cdot 3\cdot 2$, you have $3\cdot 3\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 3\cdot 1$ which is precisely 3 fewer than what you found. You cannot repeat the 4.